# NLTK part of speech Troubles

Tags: python, nltk, part-of-speech

I am having some trouble with NLTK.  I have used a list of part of speech tags I expect that when I run this code using a VBD I will get these words: (dipped, pleaded, soaked)

```
lines = ("ask, Assemble, assess, dipped, pleaded, soaked, languished, panelized, used, sue, cure, 
lengthen")
tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(lines)
verbs = [word for (word, pos) in nltk.pos_tag(tokenized) if(pos[:2] == 'VBD')]
print(verbs)
```

What I get is this: `[]`

When I run this same code but with VB part of speech tag I would expect to get (ask, Assemble, assess)

```
lines = ("ask, Assemble, assess, dipped, pleaded, soaked, languished, panelized, used, sue, cure, 
lengthen")
tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(lines)
verbs = [word for (word, pos) in nltk.pos_tag(tokenized) if(pos[:2] == 'VB')]
print(verbs)
```

what I get is: `[dipped', 'pleaded', 'soaked', 'languished', 'panelized', 'used]`

this output is VBN and VBD, not VB.

Comment: Do you know what `pos[:2]` means?

Answer (score 0):

`pos[:2]` returns the first 2 characters of `pos`, which, in the case of VBD and VBN, is... VB. If you want a specific POS tag just match on the whole tag.

```
verbs = [word for (word, pos) in nltk.pos_tag(tokenized) if(pos == 'VBD')]
```

Matching on the first few characters is only done if you want to match on a more general tagset (and in that case`startswith` is more idiomatic).

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help!